# Rewrite rules for URL prefixes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am rewriting some URL prefixes (i.e. category prefix, tag prefix or custom taxonomy prefix) in my Wordpress plugin. I am using [Wordpress' rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API):

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
add_filter('init','flushRules');  

// Remember to flush_rules() when adding rules
function flushRules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

// Adding a new rule
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['kategorie/(.+?)/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

It is working, but the system URLs on site have not changed, and WP is using the old prefix 'category' from the database. How do I rewrite those URLs as well?

Comment: Could you provide an example of a URL you expect to be rewritten and what you want it to be rewritten to?  If you haven't written a rule to rewrite that URL, try to right the rule first, then show it to us.

Comment: System WP URLs gets prefix from the database (wp_options table). And I trying dynamically rewrite those URLs. I.e. `example.com/category/fruits` need be rewrited to `example.com/kategorie/fruits`.
My rules (from my message) are working - I can open `example.com/kategorie/fruits`. But, for example, url in the breadcrumbs or any other noneditable place (doesn't matter) **have not** changed (from `/category/` to `/kategorie/`) and I can't change them. I guess what my rewrite rules fired after creating URLs, but I need call them before.

Comment: Why can't you change the options to be what you want?

Comment: @bobdye WP Database have only one field for any url prefixes (one field = one value). And if I'll change these prefixes directly in DB, it will not be dynamic because all other users will see this change. This is a reason why I try to change (rewrite) URLs only, before the WP-core will display them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the permalink structure for all categories, then you can configure that at **Settings -> Permalinks -> Category base**.

If you want to change the link for only one or a few categories, you can use the WordPress category_link filter:

```
function update_permalink( $permalink, $cat_id ) {
    // If $cat_id is category we want to change, modify $permalink
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'category_link', 'update_permalink', 11, 2 );
```